# Spring data and mongoDB - inheritance and @DBRef

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, dbref

I have this two documents, User:

```
@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {
    // fields
}
```

and Contact:

```
@Document(collection = "Contact")
public class Contact extends User{
    // fields
}
```

and then I have a document which referes either to User oder Contact:

```
@Document(collection = "DocumentFile")
public class DocumentFile {

    @DBRef
    private User user;
}
```

So I am able to add User oder Contact in DocumentFile#user but if I set a Contact to DocumentFile#user than I lost the reference because in MongoDB DocumentFile#user is stored as "_class" : "...Contact".
Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I solved it with two different fields in **DocumentFile** but I would still be interested in how to do it in the way of inheritance with basic type **User**

Comment: What do you mean by losing the reference ?  Do you problem getting data back ?

Comment: Yes, because the _class type in **DocumentFile** document is **...User** (also if it is a Contact- reference) but it should be **...Contact** and therefore when I retrieve a documentFile than user field is null.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how your classes should look like to make the DBRef work with the inheritance.

**User**

```
@Document(collection = "User")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Contact**

Please note you  don't need Document annotation on this class.

```
public class Contact extends User {

    private String address;

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

**Document File**

```
@Document(collection = "DocumentFile")
public class DocumentFile {

    @Id
    private String id;

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @DBRef
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

You'll just need the `IDocumentFileRepository` and `IUserRepository` for CRUD operations.

Rest of the code along with the test cases have been uploaded to github.

https://github.com/saagar2000/Spring